# Interceptor Headers not included in response

Tags: okhttp

Using Retrofit 2.1.0 and OkHttp 3.4.1

Test project https://github.com/liamheneghan/okhttpAuthenticatorInterceptTest

Retrofit is setup using an OkHttpClient with an Authenticator and Network Interceptor which will attach a header. When I get a 401 and enter the authenticator

```
response.request().headers()
```

Contains no headers. However, I can see that the network request did include the header from the network interceptor. Is this the correct way to access the headers attached via the Network Interceptor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
response.networkResponse().request().headers()
```

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you. I was attempting to follow the Authenticator recipe on the OkHttp wiki which appeared to access it in the manner I included above. Perhaps I misunderstood the scenario in which the recipe is used?